# Gradle platform dependencies with java-library

Tags: java, gradle, micronaut, maven-bom

We have a couple of common libraries, which use the java-library Gradle plugin, and depend on Micronaut via a platform dependency on it's BOM. Both projects use Gradle 6.6.1 which is the latest at the time of writing this post.

Library `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id "java-library"
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {

    annotationProcessor (
        platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion"),
        "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java"
    )

    implementation(
        platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion"),
        "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject"
    )

    testAnnotationProcessor(
        enforcedPlatform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion"),
        "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java"
    )

    testImplementation(
        enforcedPlatform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion"),
        "io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime",
        "io.micronaut:micronaut-http-server-netty",
        "io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client"
    )
}
```

When I try to use my library in an application, which uses the application Gradle plugin and also has a platform dependency on Micronaut's BOM, I get an error saying it can't resolve the Micronaut BOM the library uses. But it will never be able to resolve that dependency because it's a BOM, not a library.

Application `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id "application"
    id "java"
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(
        "my.group:library:${libraryVersion}",
    
        platform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:${micronautVersion}"),
        "io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client",
        "io.micronaut:micronaut-http-server-netty",
        "io.micronaut:micronaut-inject",
        "io.micronaut:micronaut-management",
        "io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime",
        "io.micronaut:micronaut-validation"
    )
}
```

And then I get the following error.

```
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionResolveException: Could not resolve io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:2.0.1.
Required by:
    project : > my.group:library:11.0.0-SNAPSHOT
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.component.NoMatchingConfigurationSelectionException: No matching variant of io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:2.0.1 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 14, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally but:
  - Variant 'apiElements' capability io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:2.0.1:
      - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a platform and the consumer needed a runtime of a library
      - Other compatible attributes:
          - Doesn't say anything about how its dependencies are found (required its dependencies declared externally)
          - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 14)
          - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
```

I've attempted to read the Gradle docs regarding variant selection, but it really doesn't make much sense to me. Anyone know how I need to declare the dependencies to make this work? It seems like a pretty trivial thing, but I haven't found anything about this...

Comment: See if `implementation(enforcedPlatform("io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion")) works in the main project.

Comment: I tried `enforcedPlatform`, but that didn't seem to make any difference. I think it just allows you to override a version of a library provided by the BOM.

Comment: @npskirk were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: I ended up fixing the symptom rather than the root cause. Something like this:


`implementation("org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:${elasticsearchVersion}") {
        force = true
        because "Micronaut 2 BOM brings in Elasticsearch 7 which is incompatible with our cluster running 6"
    }`

Comment: @333 I haven't revisited it. Sorry no info.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue. I added dependency management plugin and moved io.micronaut:micronaut-bom over there.
`dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "io.micronaut:micronaut-bom:$micronautVersion"
    }
}`

Comment: @JamesPace any updates on this?

Comment: @elect In case you're still stuck a year later I fixed this by adding `java {disableAutoTargetJvm()}` to my `build.gradle`. I found the answer in the [Upgrading Gradle version 5.x to 6.0 notes](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html#automatic_target_jvm_version)

Comment: Too late, but appreciated nonetheless, +1

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Gradle v7.4 and was able to resolve the problem by adding this to my `build.gradle`:

```gradle
java {
  disableAutoTargetJvm()
}
```

I found the answer in the [Upgrading Gradle version 5.x to 6.0 notes](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html#automatic_target_jvm_version).